# How to refer to specific column within datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, management-studio-express

I am currently creating a system within visual studio connecting to SQL database Management System. I am trying to write an if statement which takes the value that is in the specific column and if its equal to 'y' then I follow with an update statement.

I'm having trouble with the line within the brackets, the rest I am able to do.

```
if( cmnpayment = "Y")
{
  //UPDATE STATEMENT
}
```

Comment: Try using single quotes `if( cmnpayment = 'Y')`

Comment: if it's a string you could use `if(string.compare(cmnpayment,"y"))`

Comment: Can you post your declaration for cmnpayment?  What type of variable is it?